# Automapper map properties with matching prefix

Tags: automapper, conditional-statements, prefix

I am using Automapper for various mappings. Now I would like to use Automapper to update ObjectDest from ObjectSrc. Both objects are of same type, so normally all properties will be mapped, but I want only map properties which have name prefixed with "View_", the rest sould stay unmodified.

Is it possible to do this, using some kind of condition, because I would like to use it on many different objects, but always between two objects of same type

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can ignore properties of objects in a mapping by using .Ignore.  So below will automatically map all remaining properties of the objects that match, but it will ignore propA.

```
    Mapper.CreateMap<ObjectA, ObjectB>()
        .ForMember(dest => dest.propA, opt => opt.Ignore());
```